# apache http client: connection timeout for "no route to host" case

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a problem with `apache http client (4.2.1)` connection timeouts, if host exists but does not respond in time, the connection is closed by timeout (everything is as expected), but if there is no such host, the client keeps waiting longer than expected (about 12 seconds instead of 5 specified in configuration). Eventually this results in NoRouteToHostException, probably because of the specific network issues (when I was trying to reproduce this in another network, I've got socket read timeout exception after 5 sec of waiting, as expected).
I'm using the following timeout settings:

- http.socket.timeout = 5 sec
- http.connection.timeout = 5 sec

Any thoughts are appreciated.

### Update

If someone ever has the same issue, it is probably caused by the connection retries, performed by the client. I'll update this post when I solve the problem

### Update2

Eventually I've been able to fix the issue. The problem was caused by the connection retries performed by DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler, used by AbstractHttpClient (that is the parent of DefaultHttpClient), if there is no request retry handler specified explicitly. So, if you want to get rid of it, just specify the request retry handler with smaller number of retries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I've been able to fix the issue. The problem was caused by the connection retries performed by DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler, used by AbstractHttpClient (that is the parent of DefaultHttpClient), if there is no request retry handler specified explicitly. So, if you want to get rid of it, just specify the request retry handler with smaller number of retries